# Page is displayed before async call finished? Output undefined. Mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

My activity model has a property which is a reference to an ObjectId in the units table. The method works fine, in my opinion, as console logging `unit.name` logs correct name and also never hits the catch clause so there is no error in retrieval of the name, so I assume that it is being returned as well.

Unfortunately, assuming `activity` is an instance of activities, calling `activity.unit_id` in my view returns undefined and my view shows undefined. All other properties are being printed properly:

[image]

My activity model's schema:

```
var activitySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    pointsPerUnit: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    unit_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Unit',
        get: function(unit_id) {
            Unit.findById(unit_id).then((unit) => {
                console.log(unit.name)
                return unit.name
            }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what I am calling in my `.pug` file:

```
h2 All Activities

each activity in activities
    p= "Name: " + activity.name
    p= "Description: " + activity.description
    p= "Points Per Unit of Excersise: " + activity.pointsPerUnit
    p= "Unit: " + activity.unit_id
    hr
```

I am also explicity logging `mongoose` queries to my console. Here's the execution from `mongoose`, which is also correct:

```
Mongoose: units.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("592679205a7b0e0c8fe7f47f") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: units.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("592679205a7b0e0c8fe7f47f") }, { fields: {} })
```

Here is the controller code for the route:

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
    Activity.find({}).then((activities) => {
        res.render('activities/new', {activities});
    }); 
});
```

Have spent two hours on this issue with no luck! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I would second that notion that this is indeed a duplicate, but the question does not even display the controller code for the request. So it's likely the cause but unclear without the necessary code.

Comment: @NeilLunn See updated answer. This is all the relevant code I have in my project. The view renders, the route works, every field except the unit_id field displays properly. It's just that I store a foreign key to a unit and upon pulling the record from the activity I want the name of the unit and not the unit id.

Comment: Then are any results returning from `Activity.find({})` at all? Add in a `console.log()` or something to check. If empty then make sure you are actually connecting to the correct database and have the correct collection name.Noting that mongoose is expecting a collection named `"activities"` by default unless you explicitly told it otherwise.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, results are returned correctly. See the first image in my question. Its just that one property in each record is incorrect. It renders undefined. When i call `activity.unit_id` it console.log() the correct unit name but view renders undefined.

Comment: Okay. I see it now.The `get` function in the schema is not how you do this. You use the `.populate()` method instead. Modern mongoose even supports this with "virtual fields". See the documentation. But as a weird variant of the initial duplicate, you are trying to "pass in" an async method as the "getter". Which basically has the same results in consequence.

Comment: OMG. that's it! You are a god, @NeilLunn. Going from a traditional rdbms to MongoDB has been quite a challenge.. too bad teh question has a -1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define a "getter" in your schema using an async method. Instead of doing this you should be calling [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) in the controller:

**activity schema**

```
var activitySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    pointsPerUnit: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    unit_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Unit',
    }
});
```

**controller code**

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
    Activity.find({}).populate('unit_id').then((activities) => {
        res.render('activities/new', {activities});
    }); 
});
```

This makes sure the objects from `Unit` are resolved before calling the template.